# CSS transition working in webkit but not in FF

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, webkit, css-transitions

I have this code for a drop-down menu, with a transition on the sub-menu:

```
ul.menu ul {
        -moz-transition: visibility 0s linear .55s, opacity .55s linear 0s;
        -webkit-transition: visibility 0s linear .55s, opacity .55s linear 0s;
        -o-transition: visibility 0s linear .55s, opacity .55s linear 0s;
        transition: visibility 0s linear .55s, opacity .55s linear 0s;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;}

ul.menu li:hover > ul {
        -moz-transition-delay:0s;
        -o-transition-delay:0s;
        -webkit-transition-delay:0s;
        transition-delay:0s;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1; }
```

It displays properly in Chrome but not in Firefox (7.0.1): why?
Another transition changing background-color on another elemet works fine and a similar transition (www.greywyvern.com/?post=337 credit for the idea!) works as well in FF.

Comment: How are you defining "properly"?  Note that `visibility` is a discrete property, so defining how it should transition is complicated.  The spec on that has been in flux and implementations may not match each other or the current spec.

Comment: "Properly" as in the link I've posted (which by the way works in FF with a very similar code...).
I agree with you that the spec has not been "established", but as the example I've linked to works (even in FF) there must be something else.

Comment: Can you post an actual page showing the CSS above as applied to your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a CSS3 function, I assume it's still not a working feature in Firefox. Take a look at the compatibility table on the bottom of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions#AutoCompatibilityTable) page... Try upgrading your browser or work with an alternative of transitions.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many timing declarations:

```
-moz-transition: visibility 0s linear .55s, opacity .55s linear 0s;
```

If you remove the last timing `0s` it will work as expected.

[See here, with your code and with the last time removed.](http://jsfiddle.net/QJq9M/)

Comment: Mmm not working for me, and why should it? The last timing is a delay and I suppose it can be different for the two properties, I tried the non-shorthand properties as well but same result.
I'm not sure whether a child (>) can be transitioned this way though...